# I cant lower an Audio element HTML5/CSS3

Tags: css, html

So I'm busy with my first webpage and after a while added an audio element that works perfectly,
The only problem I'm having is that I can't lower the element in that way that it is on the bottem of my page.

I tried:
Googling for a very long time,
asking other people with more knowledge then me,

(worked but make a mess) Use `<br>` alot of times

These are my HTML and CSS code, if you need more please ask ;)
Also i dont want to know more then that, im busy learning and the best way to do that is doing it yourself. only with this i got very stuck.

**HTML**

```
 <audio src="music.mp3" controls>   
            <embed 
                src="music.mp3"
                width="300"
                height="90"
                loop="true"
                autostart="false" />
        </audio>
```

**CSS**

```
 audio {
    top:1200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

BTW: also tried `margin-bottom`, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [margin-top](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-top.asp) to lower the element:

```
audio {
  margin-top:50px;
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/CTD58/

Answer (score 0):

`top:1200px;` only works when you declare `position:absolute`, `position:relative` or `position:fixed`.

Either add one of these positions declarations, or add `margin-top` instead of `top`.

Alternatively, wrap the audio element in a div and position that div how you want.